# jQuery datepicker not working inside ng-repeat in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datepicker

I am using jquery ui date picker in angularjs and it is working fine. But it is not working when datepicker comes inside `ng-repeat` loop.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control date_picker" ng-model="date.date" ng-repeat="date in ot.dates">
//Directive
app.directive('otForm', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'app/components/ots/form.html',
        link: function ($scope, form) {
            $(".date_picker").datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
                prevText: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>',
                nextText: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>',
                showButtonPanel: false,
                changeYear: true,
                changeMonth: true
            });
        }
    }
})
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you show your `ng-repeat` loop? - Added, thanks

Comment: it is there in text box

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Do you see the inputs with the date value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that your DOM will have multiple `<input>`s with the class of `.date_picker` and so your jQuery selector `$(".date_picker")` is going to return an increasing number of matches as the `ng-repeat` grows. You really just want your jQuery selector to match the one directive element in your `ng-repeat`. You are in luck because the `link` function in a directive passes you the `scope` and the `element` itself:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control date_picker" ng-model="date.date" ng-repeat="date in ot.dates">
//Directive
app.directive('otForm', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'app/components/ots/form.html',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            $(element).datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
                prevText: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>',
                nextText: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>',
                showButtonPanel: false,
                changeYear: true,
                changeMonth: true
            });
        }
    }
})
```

See the change to the `link:` line and the immediately following line. I assume you have your directive implemented correctly, but not shown here. You have `restrict: 'E'` but I don't see a `<otForm`> in your `ng-repeat`.

Comment: here element is not textbox. entire temploate

Comment: Perhaps you could change the directive to `restrict: 'A'` and add `otForm` as an attribute to your `<input>`: `<input otForm type="text" ... >` so that your directive only maps to the relevant element.

Comment: I created a directive for datepicker and now it is wokring